Typechecking a ramda.js utility
This code works as expected but it's a type error bonanza. Is it actually possible to type check this code effectively or should I just give up and @ts-expect-error everything?
I do have @types/ramda installed but it's not happy with this at all, and even when I do have those types available I still find, in general, that trying to type ramda effectively is very hairy indeed (otherwise I'm a big fan of the library, thanks for all the effort maintainers).
I know there is an issue with typing pipe in general (it probably needs higher-kinded types), but other than that I'm struggling to satisfy the checker here.
Is this a lost cause?
import { camel, isArray, isObject } from 'radash';
import { T, cond, fromPairs, head, identity, juxt, last, map, o, pipe, toPairs, useWith } from 'ramda';

const camelArray: <A>(arr: A[]) => A[] = map((arr) => camelKeys(arr));

// No overload matches this call.
// The last overload gave the following error.
// Argument of type '(fn: (x: unknown) => unknown, list: readonly unknown[]) => unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type '(args_0: (x: unknown) => unknown) => unknown'.
// Target signature provides too few arguments. Expected 2 or more, but got 1.
const mapKeysAndValues = useWith(pipe(map, fromPairs), [identity, toPairs]);

// Expected 7 arguments, but got 1.
const camelObj = mapKeysAndValues(
    juxt([
        o(camel, head),
        o((x) => camelKeys(x), last),
    ]),
);

// No overload matches this call.
// The last overload gave the following error.
// Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '(value: any) => unknown'.
const camelKeys = cond([
    [isArray, camelArray],
    [isObject, camelObj],  // The above error is actually emitted at camelOj here.
    [T, identity],
]);

export { camelKeys };

if (import.meta.vitest) {
  const { expect, it } = import.meta.vitest;

  it('deep transforms all keys to camelCase', () => {
    const data = {
      snake_case: 'foo',
      an_array: [{ camelCase: 'bar', another_one: 'quux' }],
      baz: { 2: 'garply' },
    };

    const result = camelKeys(data);

    expect(result).toEqual({
      snakeCase: 'foo',
      anArray: [{ camelCase: 'bar', anotherOne: 'quux' }],
      baz: { '2': 'garply' },
    });
  });
}

